# Save numpy based array in different rows of an excel file

Tags: python, excel, numpy

I have a code that generates an `numpy.array` in each loop. I want to save the array as a row in an excel file *(i.e., the array created in the first loop becomes the first row, the array generated in the 2nd loop becomes the 2nd row and so on)*. The array is created in the following way:

for loop in `range(0,10)`:

```
Array1 = ..... 

Array2 = ......

Array3 = numpy.concatenate((Array1,Array2),axis=0)
```

Any idea how I can put Array3 in 10 different rows of an excel file? *(If the array is 5 dimensional, the excel file should contain 10 rows and 5 columns)*.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that `data` is a *list* of your arrays, and that you made sure that all your arrays have same size, you can use `np.savetxt` to save your `data` to a TSV/CSV file, as suggested by @Qnan

```
np.savetxt(your_output_file, np.array(data), delimiter="\t")
```

Check the `np.savetxt` documentation for more information on how to format the fields, if needed.

The idea is to write the file at once, instead of line by line.

Answer (score -1):

Export to a TSV or CSV (tab/comma separated value) file, Excel can open those.

Basically if you print the values to a simple text file line by line and separate those in the same line by a tab character (`'\t'`), Excel will be able to read that file. You might have to call it a `.xls` file.

Comment: You should not call it .xls...that is generally reserved for Excel's binary spreadsheet format. Just call it .txt (for TSV) or .csv (for CSV) and open it with Excel.

Comment: @nneonneo that's an option too